# Xcode Archiving with Subproject GMGridView

Tags: xcode, archive, subproject, gmgridview

I have included the GMGridView project on my project. everything runs fine when I test it on simulator, but when I try to archive it. i get the following error:

no such file or directory: '/Users/****/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/....../BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/libGMGridView.a

Tried many solutions, but still not working.

Can someone help me out on this? I really appreciate it.

Thanks!!!!